# Python Unbound Method Error

Tags: python, methods

Can someone please correct me on the mistake I have been having trouble with! The problem is that it is not generating a random integer in the Goalie nor Player class. This issue isn't allowing me to actually get both "players" to move.
Error:

```
import random
def main(): 
    name = raw_input("Name: ")
    kick = raw_input("\nWelcome " +name+ " to soccer shootout! Pick a corner to fire at! Type: TR, BR, TL, or BL! T = TOP B = BOTTOM L = LEFT R = RIGHT:  ")
    if Player.Shot == Goalie.Block:
        print("\nThe goalie dives and blocks the shot!")
    if Player.Shot != Goalie.Block:
        print("\nThe ball spirals into the net!")
        print(Player.Shot)
        print(Goalie.Block)
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Shot()
    def Shot(self):
        shot = random.randint(0,3)
        self.Shot = shot
class Goalie():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Block()

    def Block(self):
        block = random.randint(0,3)
        self.Block = block
main()
```

Comment: why not just put the code of Shot() and Block() into init?

Comment: You have an attribute (e.g. `self.Block`) and a method (e.g., erm, `self.Block`) *with the same name*. Don't do that. As @Ben says, they don't do anything sufficiently complex that you couldn't just do it in `__init__`.

Comment: Can you please code/write that example Ben?

Comment: Just an extra note - the design of assigning a variable to the name of a function is very weird. Up until the first time `Block` or `Shot` are ran in your code they are functions - after that they are ints. This is a hornets' nest maintenance, readability, and debugging-wise

Answer (score 2):

you need to instantiate the class first::

try:

```
import random
def main(): 
    name = raw_input("Name: ")
    kick = raw_input("\nWelcome " +name+ " to soccer shootout! Pick a corner to fire at! Type: TR, BR, TL, or BL! T = TOP B = BOTTOM L = LEFT R = RIGHT:  ")
    player=Player() #error fixed:<-- called the class
    goalie=Goalie() #error fixed:<-- called the class
    if player.shot == goalie.block:#error fixed:<-- used that initiated class
        print("\nThe goalie dives and blocks the shot!")
    if player.shot != goalie.block:
        print("\nThe ball spirals into the net!")
        print(player.shot)
        print(goalie.block)

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Shot()

    def Shot(self):
        shot = random.randint(0,3)
        self.shot = shot #error fixed:<-- attribute and method are same


class Goalie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Block()

    def Block(self):
        block = random.randint(0,3)
        self.block = block #error fixed:<-- attribute and method are same

main()
```